# Auto-import doesn't follow PEP8

Tags: python, import, pycharm, pep8, static-code-analysis

Consider the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = "<test>test text</test>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print(soup.find(text=re.compile(r'test$')))
```

It is missing an `import re` line and would fail with a `NameError` without it.

Now, I'm trying to use `PyCharm`'s [Auto-Import feature](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PYH/Auto-import): focusing on `re` and hitting `Alt+Enter`, which opens up the following popup:

[image]

Now, if I choose `Import 're'` option, Pycharm would insert the new import line at the top of the script:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = "<test>test text</test>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
print(soup.find(text=re.compile(r'test$')))
```

Looks almost good, except that it doesn't follow [PEP8 import guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

> Imports should be grouped in the following order:
>
> - standard library imports
> - related third party imports
> - local application/library specific imports
>
> You should put a blank line between each group of imports.

In other words, there is a missing blank line between the two imports:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

---

Question is: is it possible to tell Pycharm to follow the PEP8 guidelines and insert a new-line between the lines with different import types on auto-import?

---

As a workaround, I'm calling [Optimize Imports](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/optimizing-imports.html) after that organizes the imports correctly.

Comment: PyCharm [claims to follow PEP8 with auto-imports](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-482#comment=27-182455), so you should probably file a bug report.

Comment: This is further complicated by ambiguity of distinction between standard, related and local imports. PyCharm could be smarter, sure, but in general case you cannot authoritatively state which group given `import foo` belongs to.

Comment: @qarma that's a good point. Though, pycharm does a good job in organizing imports through `Optimize imports` in this case. This is something about auto-import here. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. Reason is PyCharm doesn't tell you that you have violated any PEP8 Guidelines if you do that or any import statements at all. One, your PyCharm is outdated (newest version is 4.0.2/4.2) or second, your PyCharm seems to be having a bug, thus giving reason to file a bug report. If you can try to *safely* download PyCharm *again* to try to fix the bug. If that doesn't work, file a bug report or make a habit of making a blank line between your statements. Hope this answers your question! Oh, it does not matter whether you use from, import, or both type of statements.

Comment: Thank you, filed an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-14765) at Pycharm's Issue Tracker.